# replace a column value having duplicates with another column if matched in MS EXCEL

Tags: excel

I have a Table, say TABLE-1 with 4 columns. Columns are (ID, NAME, GROUP_NAME, IS_APPROVER), ID is not the primary key. There are many rows with same ID. Now I got a new Table, say TABLE-2 with Columns, (NEW_ID, OLD_IDs), in this table (TABLE-2), OLD_ID is the primary Key. I have to replace all the values of IDs in TABLE-1, with the NEW_ID (in TABLE-2) values compared using OLD_ID (in TABLE-2). How can I do this?

Comment: welcome at stackoverflow. Please share with us what have you tried so far. Also please clarify your question: "I have to replace": if you want to replace original data than you either need to use  macro (probably requires some experience with VBA), either collect the data in a new column then overwrite your old range, is that a feasible way for you?

Comment: Don't replace. Just put into the new column. But give me the solution.

Comment: please update your question instead of answering in comment to let other understand your problem easier.

Comment: @MátéJuhász: My question is clearly understandable. If you can not understand means, it's not mean that no one can understand. There are some users who has given the answer for my question within an hour. See the answer given by OnePoint. He has exactly figured out my problem. If you still want me to update my question, I am ready to upload the excel screenshot. But give me the access to upload an image.

Comment: stackoverflow is a community where we help each other. More experienced users helps you to solve your problem, you should help them, and also future people looking for similar solutions to understand the problem (please have a look on help section how to ask good questions). Nobody can give access to you to upload pictures, it just depends on your points, while you can't upload one you can still upload it to a free site and paste it's link and somebody will edit your post and insert it.

Comment: @MátéJuhász: No more conversations. My question is very much clear. No worries. I don't care if you remove my question, if you don't understand. My general advise for you: DONT BLAME OTHERS TO GAIN POPULARITY.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is the solution..

Ref: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/08/13/excel-index-match-function-vlookup/

=INDEX(Table_2[NewIDs],MATCH(Table_1[@ID],Table_2[Old_ID],0))
Ex: =INDEX($K$2:$K$253,MATCH(B2,$J$2:$J$253,0))

Comment: This is the same as my solution.

Comment: No.. Your formula had given me an error. That's because, you have added one more Curly Brace just before Match(); COOL..Anyways, Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your tables look like the below:

[image: Tables example]

You should just be able to use a combination of INDEX and MATCH to get your desired results:

`=INDEX(TABLE-2[NEW_ID],(MATCH(TABLE-1[@ID],TABLE-2[OLD_IDs],0)))`

If your data is not actually in tables but in ranges the general formula is:

`=INDEX(ColumnFromWhichValueShouldBeReturned, (MATCH(LookupValue, ColumnAgainstWhichToLookup, 0)))`

**EDIT following further info from OP:**

If not all the ID's are matched in TABLE-2 you can use the following:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(TABLE-2[NEW_ID],(MATCH(TABLE-1[@ID],TABLE-2[OLD_IDs],0))), Table1[@ID])`

In practice you can see this working below:

[image: Showing the formula working in practice]

Comment: Not working for me..Some of the IDs in table1, will not be there in OLD_IDs (in Table2)

Comment: What do you want to happen for those values?

Comment: Consider the condition that Duplicates IDs are there in my TABLE-1. In your table no duplicates. Also, in New table, there are only limited Old Ids. How would u execute?

Comment: I understood but I was asking you what value you would want to appear in the IDs column if the OLD_ID doesn't have a matching NEW_ID?

Comment: Le me write the pseudocode: 1) Take the ID , say 'a' from Table-1
2)Find the corresposnding Value 'a' in Table-2
3) if matched, take the NEW_ID from Table-2 and return it.
4) else, leave the old_id. (NOTE: IDs in Table-1 have many duplicates, so the index of New_IDS in Table-2, will never match the corresponding index of Table1).

Comment: I have edited my original answer to deal with unmatched IDs by simply using the original value.

Comment: This solution is working for your table but not for me. It gives correct value for the first and rest all wrong... Just use your solution for the table uploaded by OnePoint. (see below). You will come to know what's wrong..

Comment: See my answer for evidence of my solution working for One Point's example.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use VLOOKUP to make it a little easier.
[image]

I added a new column to the first table and the formula for that column is simply

```
=VLOOKUP([@ID], Table2[#All], 2)
```

Comment: There are two issue with VLOOKUP as a solution. Firstly, his tables - given the information in the question - are not arranged in such a way that VLOOKUP can be used. Secondly, it requires the data to be sorted.

Comment: Your table is perfectly right. But your solution is not working for me..@MLucas: Please use his table and give me the solution.